# Extending two bounded linear functionals whose sum is dominated by the vector norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a real normed linear space, and $l$, $l_1$ linear functionals on a subspace $Y$ of $X$, such that $$|l(y)|+|l_1(y)|\le \|y\|, \quad y\in Y.$$

I would like to show that there exists $L, L_1 \in X^*$ that extend $l$ and $l_1$, respectively, and also $$|L(x)|+|L_1(x)|\le \|x\|, \quad x\in X.$$

I know that the extension can be made by the Han-Banach theorem, since $l, l_1$ are bounded functionals. However, I am not sure how I can guarantee that the dominance condition on the whole vector space still holds. Any thought?

Comment: Thought I had it. Good question

Comment: The question is equivalent to asking if Hahn-Banach works when the image is $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the $1$-norm. I don't think this is trivial.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva  Like with Hahn-Banach, this is easy if the domain is in a Hilbert space. But for a general normed vector space... I had never thought of that.

Comment: I found something: the Hahn-Banach-Kantorovich theorem. See [here](http://www.math.uaic.ro/~zalinesc/HB-cz.pdf). I have not yet figured out if this helps.

Comment: @julien : I'm not sure it does... it says "ordered linear spaces", which doesn't seem to be the case of $\mathbb R^2$. I can't help but notice this is homework, your teacher seems mean...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Actually, there are many ways to make $\mathbb{R}^2$ a linear ordered space. Lexicographic order is an example. Such orders are in bijection with the proper convex cones. And it seems that some of them yield the lub property, unless I'm completely wrong. But still, I'm not sure the HB-Kantorovich helps.

Comment: In categorical terms, this asks whether the codomain is injective with injectivity constant equal to $1$. Here you have $K^2$ with the $1$ norm. This is true if $K=\mathbb{R}$, false if $K=\mathbb{C}$. I confess I asked [a specialist](http://mathoverflow.net/users/2554/bill-johnson).

Comment: Actually, a finite-dimensional space is $1$-injective if and only if it is isometric to some $\ell^\infty(K^n)$.

Comment: @julien: the $\ell^1$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is isometrically isomorphic to the $\ell^{\infty}$-norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ via $(x,y) \mapsto (x+y, x-y)$ which is precisely what the answer exploits.

Comment: @Martin Yes, absolutely. But this fails in the complex case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $l_{\pm}=\frac{l\pm l_1}{2}$ on $Y$. Then $$ |l_\pm y|\le \frac{1}{2}(|ly|+|l_1y|)\le \frac{1}{2}\|y\| \quad y\in Y. $$
Extend $l_\pm$ by the Hahn-Banach theorem to $L_\pm$ on $X$, then $$ |L_\pm x| \le \frac{1}{2} \| x\|, \quad x\in X. $$
Let $ Lx=L_+x+L_-x$ and $L_1x=L_+x-L_-x$ for $x\in X$, and observe that \begin{align}
L|_Y&=l_++l_-=\frac{l+l_1}{2}+\frac{l-l_1}{2}=l\\
L_1|_Y&=l_+-l_-=\frac{l+l_1}{2}-\frac{l-l_1}{2}=l_1
\end{align}
and
$$ |Lx|+|L_1x|=|L_+x+L_-x|+|L_+x-L_-x| \le \max\{2|L_+x|, 2|L_-x|\}\le\|x\|. $$